# Setting a column value in SharePoint validation

Tags: sharepoint-online, validation, validation-list-items

I want to do an IF statement and if its true then I want another column to be set.. I am using list validation on a Sharepoint list:

```
=IF([Master vs Copy])="Master",([Duplicate Rationale])="None"), TRUE)
```

So the column called 'Duplicate Rationale' is a choice column and I want to set it to value None (which is in the columns).

*Any help would be brilliant as I don't know how to set a column in list validation.*

Answer (score 1):

We can use jQuery code to achieve it.

**Example**:

I create a custom list with the choice columns "Master vs Copy" and "Duplicate Rationale".

Then add the code below into script editor web part in the newform.aspx page.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function PreSaveItem(){ 
    var masterVsCopy=$("select[title='Master vs Copy']").val();
    var duplicateField=$("select[title='Duplicate Rationale']");
    if(masterVsCopy == "Master"){
        $("select[title='Duplicate Rationale']").val("None");
    }
    if(masterVsCopy=="Copy"&&(duplicateField.val()==""||duplicateField.val()=="None")){
        alert("Please select a value of Duplicate Rationale field.");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: perfect but not possible with Sharepoint online is it ??

Comment: SharePoint Online classic also works, in modern list, we can't add custom JavaScript in list form page.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set with Column Validation another column. Just Create Duplicate Rationale like Calculated column and here fill this expression:

```
=IF([Master vs Copy])="Master","None", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

**No**.

You cannot set the list column in validation formula.

**Solution**:

1. Create a calculated column with name `Duplicate Rationale`.
2. Use below formula for your calculated field:

   `=IF([Master vs Copy])="Master","None", "OtherValue")`

**Reference**:

1. [Calculated Field Formulas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v%3Doffice.14)).
2. [How to create calculated columns](https://sharepoint.rackspace.com/calculated-columns-tutorial).

Is there any other reason for using choice column?

Comment: because if Master vs Copy is equal to copy then Duplicate Rational has to have content.

Comment: What is the type of master vs copy?